# Flutter - TextPainter vs Paragraph for drawing book page

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to display long text, which will occupy several screens/pages. I have to add some features also, so I would like to implement my own text displaying component.

I found two classes that corresponds to this task:

- TextPainter
  use *TextSpan* for text
  use *paint(canvas, offset)* for painting
- Paragraph
  use "queue" for text and styles for them
  use *Canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, offset)* for painting

What is the difference between them and which one to use?!

If the text contains 100 lines and only 10 lines can be placed on a page, then how to draw truncated text on the next pages until nothing left?

Comment: Revisting this question, what was the final way to go? Paragraph, or something else? Thanks @serge-breusov.

Answer (score 43):

*<sub>tl;dr: imo `TextPainter` > `Paragraph` (because of better API).</sub>*

I created [simple example app](https://github.com/PsychoXIVI/flutter_textpainer_vs_paragraph) to compare both [`TextPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html) and [`Paragraph`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph-class.html) methods of rendering text on [`Canvas`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) (of `CustomPainter`). Both methods are pretty good, both uses different approaches, both have their weird wobbles.

### `TextPainter`

At first I want to mention that `TextPainter` interface seems to be easier - at least for me. You just need to specify `text` as [`TextSpan`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) entry or tree and - what is weird, it isn't default - `textDirection`. You can also provide options such as `maxLines`, `style` and `textAlign` (and few others). Then you need to use `layout` to specify how the rendering would be laying (well, `maxWidth` only). And finally, `paint` on certain `Canvas` at specified `Offset`.

```
        final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
        )
          ..layout(maxWidth: size.width - 12.0 - 12.0);  
        textPainter.paint(canvas, const Offset(12.0, 36.0));
```

Used `TextSpan` is quite universal around the Flutter - `RichText` and other widgets also are using this class. I also must notice that using **`TextPainter` allows you to check `height` and `width` of text in pixels** (before rendering).

### `Paragraph`

Second: `Paragraph`. This seems to be more underlying, procedural method. As you can see below, `Paragraph` method is less cleaner. First you must use `ParagraphBuilder` (since `Paragraph` have no constructor). You need to feed it with [`ParagraphStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ParagraphStyle-class.html) that contains various text styling such as font information, `textAlign`, `maxLines` and so on. Then you can use `pushStyle`, `pop` and `addText` to prepare next and next portion of the paragraph. After `build` you get the `Paragraph` which you can `drawParagraph` on your `Canvas`.

```
        final ui.ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
          ui.ParagraphStyle(
            fontSize:   style.fontSize,
            fontFamily: style.fontFamily, 
            fontStyle:  style.fontStyle,
            fontWeight: style.fontWeight,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          )
        )
          ..pushStyle(style.getTextStyle())
          ..addText(text);
        final ui.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphBuilder.build()
          ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: size.width - 12.0 - 12.0)); 
        canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, const Offset(12.0, 36.0));
```

Be aware, there is two types of `TextStyle` (Dart UI and Flutter). In line with `pushStyle` you can see that [Flutter Painting library `TextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) got transformed into [Dart UI `TextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextStyle-class.html). Another weird thing is that you can/need specify few font settings just in the `ParagraphBuilder` - even though you are going to use `pushStyle` in the line after. And the `layout` must be specified with `width`.

I think I could be better to use in situations like reading file, especially with formatting, since there will be no need to parse the file into `TextSpan` tree, which could be costly. I suppose it can be also a bit faster than other methods if you are know what you are doing, but I do not have time to dig it that deeply.

### Max lines problem

You might want to clip the text when there is too much of it. Both `Paragraph` and `TextPainter` exposes `maxLines` - to set max lines - and `didExceedMaxLines` - to detect whether the limit was exceeded -, in one way or another. There is also `canvas.clipRect` and related methods which allows to clip all drawing into selected space.

### Performance

There is also simple [performance test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G8PZX06kdOSlrIL6A_gQFzIbMLQsUpZtCMe2VAUO8aE/edit#gid=0) (on release), which shows that both methods are comparable (in my testing case `TextPainter` was no more than 2% faster than `Paragraph`). It might be also measurement error ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 1):

My Current Solution is using painter to check if text out of availabe constraint.

```
List<Widget> _chapterPages = List.empty(growable:true);
int _fontSize = 12;
String _fontFamily = "Roboto";
String _text ="aaaaaa \n\n aaaaa";

_setPages(String text, BoxConstraints constraints) async {        

     var style = TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize, fontFamily: _fontFamily);
     var span = TextSpan(
                  text: text,
                  style: style,
                 );

     //painter to check height overflow
     var painter = TextPainter(
         text: span,
         maxLines: null,
         textScaleFactor: 1,
         textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );
      painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

     final overflowH = painter.size.height > constraints.maxHeight;

     double charWidth = 0.48 * _fontSize; //this coefisient still dodgy 
     double charHeight = painter.preferredLineHeight;
     int charInLine = constraints.maxWidth ~/ charWidth;
     int lines = constraints.maxHeight ~/ charHeight;
     
     // cut string base on rough estimate of characters allowed in boxconstraints 
     if (overflowH) {
       
       int splitStart = (charInLine * lines).toInt();
       String newText = text.substring(0, splitStart);
       
       //do final calculation for char allowed in boxconstraint SS
       splitStart = getSplitIndex(constraints: constraints, text: newText, style: style);

       String nextText = text.substring(splitStart, text.length);

       text = text.substring(0, splitStart);
       // debugPrint("textSubstring: ${text}");
       span = TextSpan(
         text: text,
         style: style,
       );

       _setPages(nextText, constraints);
     }

   var newPage = SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Container(
       // color: overflowH ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
       child: Text.rich(
         span,
         style: style,
         textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        ),
      ),
     );

   _chapterPages.add(newPage);
}
```

i use this 2 functions to cut paragraphs that overflowing boxconstraints

```
 int getSplitIndex({required BoxConstraints constraints, required String text, required style}) {
   // debugPrint("textSubstring: ${newText}");

   int splitStart = text.length;
   TextSpan span = TextSpan(
     text: text,
     style: style,
   );

   // cek if painter still exceed constraints
   var painter = TextPainter(
      text: span,
      maxLines: null,
      textScaleFactor: 1,
      textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
   );
   painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

   final overFlowH = painter.height > constraints.maxHeight;

   if (!overFlowH) return splitStart;

   //check paragraph
   List<RegExpMatch> listParagraph = getListParagraphRegMatch(text);
   if (listParagraph.length > 1) {
     splitStart = listParagraph[listParagraph.length - 2].end;
     debugPrint('lastParagraph: $splitStart');
     text = text.substring(0, splitStart);
     return getSplitIndex(constraints: constraints, text: text, style: style);
   }

   return splitStart;
  }

   List<RegExpMatch> getListParagraphRegMatch(String newText) {
       RegExp regExp = RegExp(
         r"((?:[^\n][\n]?)+)",
         multiLine: true,
       );

       if (newText.isNotEmpty) return regExp.allMatches(newText).toList();
       return List.empty();
     }
```

and the i call the `_setPages()` in layout builder

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SafeArea(
     child: Scaffold(
      body:Column(
        children:[
          Expanded(
           child:_chapterPages.isNotEmpty
                ? PageView(
                    controller: _pageViewController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        curPage = index + 1;
                      });
                    },
                    children: [
                      for (var page in _chapterPages.reversed) page,
                    ],
                  )
                : LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (ctx, constraints) {
                      //to make sure setState not called before layout builder finish being build
                      Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
                          _setPages(text,constraints);
                          setState((){});
                      });
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        ]
      ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

this is part of my code,

Answer (score 1):

`TextPainter` is built on `ParagraphBuilder`. It allows you to change any of properties and then comparing the change to see if layout needs to be rebuilt. Performance depends on your use case. if your changes often won't needs to rebuild layout, `TextPainter` will perform better. But if your changes require rebuilding layout, for example, changing text, `TextPainter` will perform worse because comparing changes make it even slower.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a use-case based insight on this !