# How to render large text(size varies) into multiple pages with horizontal scroll, if flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can we render large text(text length and font size varies) into multiple pages with horizontal scroll, if flutter? Also can we calculate number of pages before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter - TextPainter vs Paragraph for drawing book page

> [Render text to multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588693/7664149)

Comment: If this answer is helpful please upvote this

Comment: Hi @allence vakharia, I was able to render text in single page, but if I need to scroll to next(page view type) based on excess text, is there an option?